# AngularJS: functions not executing in dynamically created ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-repeat

This question is building off of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26683946/angularjs-custom-directive-within-ng-repeat-with-dynamic-attributes-and-two-way).  Basically, I have a directive that creates an ng-repeat that iterates over a dynamically changing collection.  (What I mean by dynamically changing is that the JSON data is often updated with new collections).

The functions that are within these ng-repeats are not being called, i.e. I don't see them on the console. The items for the ng-repeats are showing up in the view. However, when I use a regular ng-repeat and iterate over a specific collection, the actions work fine.  I'm guessing there's some problem with the directive (dyn-ng-repeat) that deals with ng-repeat, but I can't figure it out.

Here's an example of the JSON. model1 and model2 are different collections, and more collections - such as model3 and model4 - will be created later with similar structures. On a view, I only want to show one model, not all of them.

```
{
    {
        "model": "model1",
        "children": [
         {
            "action": "removeChild",
            "model": "item",
            "text" : "remove this child"
         }
        ]
     },
     {
        "model": "model2",
        "children": [
         {
            "action": "removeChild",
            "model": "item",
            "text" : "remove this child"
         }
        ]
     }
 }
```

Here's the HTML:

```
<div ng-repeat="field in fields">    
 <div dyn-ng-repeat="item in {{field.model}}">
  <div ng-repeat="field in field.children">
   <div dyn-click click-action="{{field.action}}" click-model=" {{field.model}}">{{field.text}}</div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

As I mentioned earlier, when I change the first line of the HTML code to `<div ng-repeat="item in model1">`, the functions within the ng-repeat children are called and execute fine.  With dyn-ng-repeat, the items do show up, they just aren't executing their functions.

Here's the code for the dyn-ng-repeat directive:

```
'use strict';

exports = module.exports = function (ngModule) {
    ngModule.directive('dynNgRepeat', function($compile){
        return{
         scope:true,
         link:function(scope,element,attr){
            element[0].removeAttribute('dyn-ng-repeat');
            element[0].setAttribute('ng-repeat', attr.dynNgRepeat + ' track by $index');
            $compile(element[0])(scope);
        }
    };
 });
};
```

Here's the code for the dyn-click directive:

```
'use strict';

exports = module.exports = function (ngModule) {
  ngModule.directive("dynClick",function($compile) {
    return {
      restrict: 'A',
      scope:true,
      link: function(scope,element,attrs) {
         $(element).click(function(e, rowid){
               scope.$eval(attrs["clickAction"]) (scope.$parent.$eval(attrs["clickModel"]), scope.$index);
            });
        }
    };
  });
};
```

The function removeChild is executed from a parent controller and is meant to delete that child:

```
exports = module.exports = function (ngModule) {
  ngModule.controller('HomeCtrl', function ($scope, $timeout, $http, $state,      $stateParams, limitToFilter, Restangular, $rootScope, $translate) {

  $scope.removeChild = function(model, index){
      $rootScope.field.model.splice(index, 1);
      $scope.$digest();
  };

};
```

Any ideas on why the removeChild function is not executing with the dyn-ng-repeat directive?

I also created a Plunker regarding this issue: http://plnkr.co/edit/fFyMPlIK1LJMM4cfU0ld?p=preview.  However, in the Plunker, the function is being called but having problems.  I really don't know why the function is being called in the Plunker, but not in my app.  I've been at this for few days, and at this point, a fresh perspective would probably help.

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: Your plunker has plenty of errors in the console - fix them first

Comment: What is the purpose of these directives that do the same thing as the normal directives? This 'dynNgRepeat' does the exact same thing, get rid of that sucker, same the the dynClick. Just use ng-click. Since the problems are only inside of those directives, it probably has something to do with the scopes they are creating. Get rid of those.

Comment: Your code is too big and probably contains more than one conceptual/coding error. Try to reduce the plunkr to the minimum amount of code that reproduce your error. Maybe you will even understand it while doing that.

Comment: New Dev & floribon - I'll work on that.  Just letting you know that it might take a few hours.

Comment: ribsies - the model for each ng-repeat and click action is being dynamically generated, and I need a custom directive to change that data into a model that ng-repeat and a click action that Angular will understand.